# Have Samba "proxy" for another server?

Tags: ubuntu, samba

This might be a weird question, but can you have Samba "proxy" for another server? IE if mount a share on `\\server1\someshare` the server transparently proxies it to `\\otherserver\randomshare`.

Note that redirection will not work since `\\otherserver` is not directly accessible. The servers run Ubuntu Server 12.04.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're allowed to have `\\othershare\randomshare` permanently mounted on `server1`, mount that with [smbfs](http://www.samba.org/samba/smbfs/) and then configure Samba to serve it as `someshare`. Not really proxying, but it will give you the behavior asked for in the question.

Alternatively, you could turn off Samba on `server1`, and instead use an ssh tunnel that forwards traffic on port 139 to `otherserver`. See [Setting up Samba over SSH Tunnel HOWTO](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/Samba-with-SSH/).

Comment: Is that really better than re-exporting an NFS mount?

Comment: No, but you never indicated that `otherserver` was serving via NFS.

Comment: Its my current solution. I was wondering if there was a better one that only uses samba

Comment: I see. Edited to add another possible solution using ssh.